# SetTitle Doesn't Change the Text of a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Pretty straight forward; just trying to change the display name of my button from "Button" to "a." But the setTitle method doesn't seem to do anything. I played around with the UIState, and that didn't seem to change much.

Do I maybe need to synthesize anything?

```
[Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

EDIT:
I did an NSLog, and the button is showing as NULL, which I've been told means it isn't connected properly. But I double-checked my Connections Inspector, looked at the H file, and everything seems to link up fine. ([http://imgur.com/EFsp51U](https://imgur.com/EFsp51U)) What am I missing?

[image: H file and Connections Inspector]

Comment: Are you sure your UIButton outlet is wired up correctly for Button1?

Comment: In the Connections Inspector, when I hover over the Button1 connector, it highlights the appropriate button. My H file shows the Button1 IBOutlet as being connected. Is there another way to check besides those two?

Comment: It's in a Void method, within a switch statement, inside the ViewController.m file.

Comment: Can you please write more code? As what you are telling seems quite difficult to happen ever - otherwise you are making some else mistake. Because the line of code that you have written is perfectly valid.

Comment: Please verify that you have not setImage to that UIButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went digging through my code, and in my viewDidLoad method, I had the following:

```
Button1 = NO;
```

I think I was trying to type out "selected" but got distracted and didn't come back to it, and so was inadvertently turning my own button off. The correct code is:

```
self.Button1.selected=NO;

[self.Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have created your button in Interface Builder, then go there and change its type to custom.

[image]

And also check if you have connected your `IBOutlet` correctly.

Comment: I did build the button through the Interface Builder, but changing to custom didn't seem to correct the issue. I double-checked the outlet, and it seems everything is wired up.
Are there any potential issues for having straight IBOutlets instead of properties in the H file?

Comment: In this case, it should work. Your IBOutlets are connected correctly. Its weird that title is not set.

Comment: Weird, mine was set to System. Changing it to Custom worked. What's the difference again?

Comment: here is a detailed answer for difference between custom and system buttons.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468314/3081929

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `Button1` is not `nil`
- Make sure Button1.hidden = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have synthesized your Button.

```
//this assumes you have a button "myButton" declared in your interface file
@implementation
@synthesize myButton;

-(void) myMethod{
    [myButton setTitle:@"The new Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

You should have your button connected through IB outlets to your .h file *or* create the button entirely through code.

Also it is good practice to not have variable names beginning with a capital letter.

Comment: You can't say, `You should have your button connected through IB outlets to your .h file`. You can have them in a `.m` file as well and this is more common now-a-days.

Comment: `forControlState` is invalid. it's `forState`

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to synthesize IBOutlets anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the problem is about thread but you may want to try to set the title on main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Do

   ```
   NSLog(@"%@", Button1);
   ```

   and check that it's not nil.
2. Check that

   ```
   NSLog(@"%d", btn.state);
   ```

   should return 0.

Comment: When I do option 1 and set a breakpoint right after, Button1=(UIButton *) nil. The NSLog itself shows (null) Am I reading it right that it's not getting that string assigned? But why? (The 2nd option doesn't return anything at all.)

Comment: Have you taken the Button in the XIb then check in the IBOutlet connection. Check you have not set Button1=nil in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly valid. But just to make sure everything is ok, add following extra line,

```
Button1.selected = NO;
[Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't explicitly synthesized it then you should be calling either

`[_Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

or

`[self.Button1 setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: I'm not creating the buttons as properties, but putting them between {} under the @interface in the H file. When I try to do self or _, I get an error. Should I still be synthesizing them?

Comment: @Michelle I think best practice would be to declare them as properties. Not to say that this is the problem. NSHipster.com has a good article on it this week. To quote 

`As with anything in modern Objective-C, properties are preferred to direct ivar access. The same is true of IBOutlets:`

http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/

Comment: In modern objective c properties will be automatically synthesized for you.